# get the running upload on s3 service using awssdk

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, file-upload

I'm using S3 from aws, when i upload a file, I would like to keep all the uploads in progress, so that after a certain number of uploads in parallel, the user cannot transfer any more.

1. get running upload
2. if runningUpload > maxAuthorizeUpload then stop
3. else upload to s3

I've no idea how can I check current upload

Answer (score 1):

You can use ThreadPoolTaskExecutor for executing multithread tasks, each per upload and check the active number of threads with getActiveCount() method, if this reach maxAuthorizedUpload, don´t add new thread for that upload.